# Perform operations at the end of a JBoss 7 deployment

Tags: java, java-ee-6, jboss7.x, jboss-weld

We have an application that needs to do some initialization at the end of a deployment (in a JBoss 7.1.0 instance) because only then will all the required services be available (there are quite a few of them).

One approach we tried was this:

We have a singleton service along with an @Startup annotation but we so far were not successful in telling JBoss to create the instance last without too much hassle.

We could use `@DependsOn` but we'd have to maintain an ever growing and already large list of dependencies and thus we'd rather do that only as a last resort.

In the old days (JBoss 4 and 5) there was a possibility to define a dependency on the application (like `@Depends("myapp.ear")`)  which causes exactly what we need.

As of JBoss 7 things have changed but I assume there's still a way to do that.

Another approach was to try and create our own JBoss subsystem which is invoked after all other subsystems are started but we were not able to find a way to wait for the other subsystems to finish before performing the operations we need.

What other options could we look into?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a servlet e.g. BootstrapServlet.java, defined with the setting load-on-startup>1 /load-on-startup> in your WEB-INF/web.xml and do the initialization in that servlet.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. However, we often have more than one WAR in our EAR and would have to define their startup order (which should be possible) - and in some cases we might not even have a WAR and thus no web.xml.

Comment: other thing to consider could be, checking if the service(s) are availeble in a loop .. or do the initialization time based, so the startup class or servlet waits x minuts before starting to initialize.. often deployment is fast so could be just 1 minut ..
a last think could be to have the services register themselfs when ready (if this is possible with the services) so you can check in a loop when all services are ready

Answer (score 1):

You could put a class annotated with `@Startup` into a different EAR, or better WAR. A WAR will - I think - by default be deployed after any EAR without having to configure anything.

In the startup class, you can just invoke the actual initialization, which is deployed together with the rest of your application with `myapp.ear`. The invocation is done through an EJB local or remote interface.

Comment: That could be an option but normally I'd want to not have to create another application just to initialize the first one. Thanks for the hint however.